# how to send variable from .ui file to another .ui file in the main python file

Tags: pyqt, pyqt5, python-3.6

i have two .ui files that converted to python using pyuic5. first converted ui file is (LoginWindowUI.py) as below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_LoginWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, LoginWindow):
        LoginWindow.setObjectName("LoginWindow")
        LoginWindow.setWindowModality(QtCore.Qt.NonModal)
        LoginWindow.setEnabled(True)
        LoginWindow.resize(446, 182)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Fixed)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(LoginWindow.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        LoginWindow.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        LoginWindow.setMouseTracking(False)
        LoginWindow.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        LoginWindow.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Persian, QtCore.QLocale.Iran))
        LoginWindow.setDocumentMode(False)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(LoginWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(194, 30, 187, 77))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.password_ldt = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        self.password_ldt.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Persian, QtCore.QLocale.Iran))
        self.password_ldt.setText("")
        self.password_ldt.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Password)
        self.password_ldt.setCursorPosition(0)
        self.password_ldt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.password_ldt.setObjectName("password_ldt")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password_ldt, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.password_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.password_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.password_lbl.setObjectName("password_lbl")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.password_lbl, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.username_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.layoutWidget)
        self.username_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username_lbl.setObjectName("username_lbl")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.username_lbl, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.username_ldt = QtWidgets.QLineEdit(self.layoutWidget)
        sizePolicy = QtWidgets.QSizePolicy(QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred, QtWidgets.QSizePolicy.Preferred)
        sizePolicy.setHorizontalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setVerticalStretch(0)
        sizePolicy.setHeightForWidth(self.username_ldt.sizePolicy().hasHeightForWidth())
        self.username_ldt.setSizePolicy(sizePolicy)
        self.username_ldt.setLocale(QtCore.QLocale(QtCore.QLocale.Persian, QtCore.QLocale.Iran))
        self.username_ldt.setText("")
        self.username_ldt.setEchoMode(QtWidgets.QLineEdit.Normal)
        self.username_ldt.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.username_ldt.setObjectName("username_ldt")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.username_ldt, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.login_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.login_btn.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ClosedHandCursor))
        self.login_btn.setAutoDefault(False)
        self.login_btn.setDefault(False)
        self.login_btn.setObjectName("login_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.login_btn, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        self.description_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.description_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(30, 40, 141, 41))
        self.description_lbl.setText("")
        self.description_lbl.setAlignment(QtCore.Qt.AlignCenter)
        self.description_lbl.setWordWrap(True)
        self.description_lbl.setObjectName("description_lbl")
        LoginWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(LoginWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 446, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu.setObjectName("menu")
        LoginWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(LoginWindow)
        self.statusbar.setCursor(QtGui.QCursor(QtCore.Qt.ArrowCursor))
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        LoginWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action_cra = QtWidgets.QAction(LoginWindow)
        self.action_cra.setObjectName("action_cra")
        self.action_db = QtWidgets.QAction(LoginWindow)
        self.action_db.setObjectName("action_db")
        self.action_exit = QtWidgets.QAction(LoginWindow)
        self.action_exit.setObjectName("action_exit")
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_cra)
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_db)
        self.menu.addSeparator()
        self.menu.addAction(self.action_exit)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(LoginWindow)
        self.action_exit.triggered.connect(LoginWindow.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(LoginWindow)
        LoginWindow.setTabOrder(self.username_ldt, self.password_ldt)
        LoginWindow.setTabOrder(self.password_ldt, self.login_btn)

    def retranslateUi(self, LoginWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        self.password_ldt.setToolTip(_translate("LoginWindow", "رمز عبور خود را وارد کنید."))
        self.password_lbl.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", " رمز عبور "))
        self.username_lbl.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", "نام کاربری"))
        self.username_ldt.setToolTip(_translate("LoginWindow", "لطفاً نام کاربری خود را وارد نمایید."))
        self.login_btn.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", "ورود"))
        self.menu.setTitle(_translate("LoginWindow", "درباره ما"))
        self.action_cra.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", "A"))
        self.action_db.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", "B"))
        self.action_exit.setText(_translate("LoginWindow", "خروج"))
        self.action_exit.setStatusTip(_translate("LoginWindow", "خروج"))
        self.action_exit.setShortcut(_translate("LoginWindow", "Ctrl+Q"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    LoginWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_LoginWindow()
    ui.setupUi(LoginWindow)
    LoginWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and the second converted .ui file is (MainWindowUI.py) as below:

```
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets

class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(452, 432)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.cralogo_lbl = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.cralogo_lbl.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(90, 30, 171, 161))
        self.cralogo_lbl.setText("")
        self.cralogo_lbl.setPixmap(QtGui.QPixmap("../../.designer/backup/ICONS/CraLogo.png"))
        self.cralogo_lbl.setScaledContents(True)
        self.cralogo_lbl.setObjectName("cralogo_lbl")
        self.exit_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.exit_btn.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(140, 340, 125, 40))
        self.exit_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.exit_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.exit_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.exit_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.exit_btn.setObjectName("exit_btn")
        self.layoutWidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 10, 389, 152))
        self.layoutWidget.setObjectName("layoutWidget")
        self.gridLayout = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget)
        self.gridLayout.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout.setObjectName("gridLayout")
        self.mobile_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.mobile_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.mobile_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.mobile_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.mobile_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.mobile_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.mobile_btn.setObjectName("mobile_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.mobile_btn, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.dataentry_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.dataentry_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.dataentry_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.LeftToRight)
        self.dataentry_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.dataentry_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.dataentry_btn.setObjectName("dataentry_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.dataentry_btn, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.village_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.village_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.village_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.village_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.village_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.village_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.village_btn.setObjectName("village_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.village_btn, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.fix_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.fix_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.fix_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.fix_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.fix_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.fix_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.fix_btn.setObjectName("fix_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.fix_btn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.post_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.post_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.post_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.post_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.post_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.post_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.post_btn.setObjectName("post_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.post_btn, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.city_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget)
        self.city_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.city_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.city_btn.setLayoutDirection(QtCore.Qt.RightToLeft)
        self.city_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.city_btn.setChecked(False)
        self.city_btn.setObjectName("city_btn")
        self.gridLayout.addWidget(self.city_btn, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.layoutWidget1 = QtWidgets.QWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.layoutWidget1.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(20, 190, 389, 134))
        self.layoutWidget1.setObjectName("layoutWidget1")
        self.gridLayout_2 = QtWidgets.QGridLayout(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.gridLayout_2.setContentsMargins(0, 0, 0, 0)
        self.gridLayout_2.setObjectName("gridLayout_2")
        self.rep4_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep4_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep4_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep4_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep4_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep4_btn.setObjectName("rep4_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep4_btn, 0, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rep1_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep1_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep1_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep1_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep1_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep1_btn.setObjectName("rep1_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep1_btn, 0, 1, 1, 1)
        self.report_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.report_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.report_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.report_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.report_btn.setObjectName("report_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.report_btn, 0, 2, 1, 1)
        self.rep5_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep5_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep5_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep5_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep5_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep5_btn.setObjectName("rep5_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep5_btn, 1, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rep2_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep2_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep2_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep2_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep2_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep2_btn.setObjectName("rep2_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep2_btn, 1, 1, 1, 1)
        self.rep6_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep6_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep6_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep6_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep6_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep6_btn.setObjectName("rep6_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep6_btn, 2, 0, 1, 1)
        self.rep3_btn = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.layoutWidget1)
        self.rep3_btn.setEnabled(False)
        self.rep3_btn.setMinimumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep3_btn.setMaximumSize(QtCore.QSize(125, 40))
        self.rep3_btn.setCheckable(False)
        self.rep3_btn.setObjectName("rep3_btn")
        self.gridLayout_2.addWidget(self.rep3_btn, 2, 1, 1, 1)
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 452, 21))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        self.exit_btn.clicked.connect(MainWindow.close)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.cralogo_lbl.setStatusTip(_translate("MainWindow", "www.cra.ir"))
        self.exit_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "خروج"))
        self.mobile_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.dataentry_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "A"))
        self.village_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.fix_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))
        self.post_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.city_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.rep4_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "4"))
        self.rep1_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "1"))
        self.report_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "B"))
        self.rep5_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "5"))
        self.rep2_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "2"))
        self.rep6_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "6"))
        self.rep3_btn.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "3"))


if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    MainWindow = QtWidgets.QMainWindow()
    ui = Ui_MainWindow()
    ui.setupUi(MainWindow)
    MainWindow.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())
```

and my main python file is:

```
from LoginWindowUI import Ui_LoginWindow
from MainWindowUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, db_user, db_pass, parent=None):
        super(Main_Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_LoginWindow):
    logged = QtCore.pyqtSignal()

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.authenticate)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def authenticate(self):
        self.db_user = self.username_ldt.text()
        self.db_pass = self.password_ldt.text()
        if self.db_user == 'admin' and self.db_pass=='admin':
            self.logged.emit()
            self.close()

def call_Main_Window(username,password):
    w = Main_Window(username, password)
    w.setWindowTitle=username
    w.show()

def main():
    import sys

    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)

    login = LoginWindow()
    login.show()

    login.logged.connect(lambda :call_Main_Window(login.db_user, login.db_pass))

    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```

I want that when user enter "admin","admin" in username and password this window colsed and open second ui file .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main problem is that "w" is a local variable that will be deleted after running the function. One possible solution is to create the second window and not show it, in that second window you will have a method that receives the credentials and shows the window. In the case of the first window it is advisable to modify the signal so that it transmits both data.

```
from LoginWindowUI import Ui_LoginWindow
from MainWindowUI import Ui_MainWindow
from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Main_Window(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(Main_Window, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot(str, str)
    def setCredentials(self, db_user, db_pass):
        print(db_user, db_pass)
        self.show()

class LoginWindow(QtWidgets.QMainWindow, Ui_LoginWindow):
    logged = QtCore.pyqtSignal(str, str)

    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super(LoginWindow, self).__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.login_btn.clicked.connect(self.authenticate)

    @QtCore.pyqtSlot()
    def authenticate(self):
        self.db_user = self.username_ldt.text()
        self.db_pass = self.password_ldt.text()
        if self.db_user == 'admin' and self.db_pass=='admin':
            self.logged.emit(self.db_user, self.db_pass)
            self.close()

def main():
    import sys
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication(sys.argv)
    w = Main_Window()
    login = LoginWindow()
    login.logged.connect(w.setCredentials)
    login.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec_())

if __name__ == '__main__': 
    main()
```